# Modifying Default Windows 11 System Font

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-11

[Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/) is an app that allows for easy application of various hacks for Windows - where previously it would've taken manually changing settings or editing the registry it's now a click of a button.

One of the tweaks it offers is changing the default system font:

[image]

When I do that, however, I found that the start menu becomes glitchy - the things I've discovered include pinned folders not working and the search bar in the start menu not working either. I noticed that changing the fonts elsewhere (as seen in the sidebar) works fine (i.e., I've yet to find system-breaking glitches as with the system font), though.

I don't expect any official support out of this hack of course but it would be nice to know what is going on and if it's possible to fix.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should report this as a bug. The author is responding to emails sent from the form at the bottom of [Winaero Tweaker FAQ](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker-faq/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the information, in the mean time anyone who knows a potential solution to this is welcome to share

Answer (score 0):

is not an Winaero problem...
even changing system Font manually using registry You have the same problem
the most noticeable problem is: **any input on Start Menu doesent work**

this problem (like many other problem to customize and personalization) is why Windows are crap for everything, the only good stuff on Windows is gaming perfomance at moment... the rest is pure trash and nothing else!

how many times have spended all developers for customize a dev-trap?

personalization is also optimization of work and is important for two things:

- productivity
- mental healt (psychological)

You can joke about my comment... but think about this: do you live and work better in a room organized by you with all the things in the right place (as you have decided), or in a wrong room where you can practically change almost nothing?

Microsoft its an evil-company, and it imposes the same mental pattern on Windows users! its not conspiracy nor paranoia, its a fact... almost any other operating system doesnt have these problems and allows easy changes, as do most programs for Windows and Linux

*but all you will continue to pretend that MS is only Bill gates!*

Comment: Please remove the rant, otherwise this may get downvoted or deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1239184)

Comment: is not a rant... its an opinion